# How to store an instance reference in a class constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, reference

How do you pass in an instance reference to a class constructor and store that reference to a private variable?

I'm doing:

```
class MyClass{

private:

    OtherClass obj;

public:

    MyClass(OtherClass &_obj){
        obj = _obj;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make `obj` a reference member. And you have to use [member initialize list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to initialize it since reference member can't be default-initialized.

```
class MyClass {
private:
    OtherClass& obj;
public:
    MyClass(OtherClass &_obj) : obj(_obj) {}
};
```

Note you need to guarantee the reference won't become invalid during the object's lifetime.

Comment: To help catch some object lifetime issues, you may also want to delete the version of the constructor that accepts a temporary, i.e., `MyClass(OtherClass &&) = delete;`